# If each $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, prove that $\sum a_n x^n \to +\infty$ as $x\to1^-$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

> **Exericise 9.36:** If each $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, prove that $\sum a_n x^n \to +\infty$ as $x\to1^-$. (Assuming $\sum a_n x^n$ converges for $|x|<1$.

Here's what I tried:

Since $\sum a_n$ diverges, for $M>0$, $\exists N$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^N a_k >M.$ I want to show that for $M>0$, there exists $\delta$ such that, whenever $\delta<x<1$ implies that there exists $p$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^p a_k>M$.

I was reading [this solution](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch9.pdf) and I don't get how the "then by continuity" part implies (**) part. Could someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_nx^n$.  Since this is continuous, $\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists\delta<1$ such that $\delta<x<1$ implies
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kx^k<\epsilon$$

Let $\epsilon=\sum a_k-M$.  Choose $N$, such that $\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k>M$.  Now,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} a_kx^k>\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k-\epsilon=M.$$

Comment: How do we get the first inequality? Are you saying that when $x$ is close to $1$, $f(x)$ is close to $f(1)$? But $f(x)$ is not continuous at $1$.

Comment: I believe by $f(x)$ you mean $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kx^k$. If that's the case, you're right, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$. However, the partial sum $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx^k$ is a polynomial and so is continuous at $x=1$.