# What is intuition behind the power series question?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation, power-series

If each $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, prove that $\sum a_n x^n \to +\infty$ as $x\to1^-$.

I found this question in Apostol. It can be compared to a result of Abel's theorem. What is the intuition behind this problem and how to solve this?

I saw this question in math stack exchange also:

[If each $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, prove that $\sum a_n x^n \to +\infty$ as $x\to1^-$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1069788/9464)

but I did not understand its solution.So I am looking for an intuition behind this problem.

Can someone provide me with a better solution for the same problem?

Comment: I think I could provide an excellent solution to this.....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you write it in answer?

Comment: Can you show your work for your attempted solution?

Comment: @EricTowers I cannot make out what to start with.I think that the notion of continuity of power series will be used somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If each $a_n >0$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, prove that $\sum a_n x^n \to +\infty$ as $x\to1^-$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069788/if-each-a-n-0-and-sum-a-n-diverges-prove-that-sum-a-n-xn-to-infty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $\sum_{n=1}^M a_n > N$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n \ge \sum_{n=1}^M a_n x^n > N$ if $x$ is close enough to $1$.

Comment: Did you really want to use $N$ in two different ways?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Please write the complete answer...

Comment: @KishalaySarkar : You requested an intuition, not a solution.  Additionally, you report trouble understanding a different solution, but do not link that solution, so there is no way to avoid replicating it here.

Comment: @EricTowers Can you help me to answer this question?

Comment: @Robert Israel I do not understand the meaning.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar What part don't you understand?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The entire process is seeming unclear to me,why I am working with partial sums instead of the infinite power series and all that?

Comment: Because if all $a_n > 0$, the infinite sum $\ge$ each partial sum.